How to upload file to another user's google drive using nestjs and reactjs?
Here is my context:

Teachers create assignments and will select the folder in their Google Drive where students will submit their assignments.
When students submit assignments, their work is saved to the teacher's folder on Google Drive.
My question is: How to do this?

I am using Google Picker in a React app to let teachers pick a folder in their Google Drive. Once the teacher selects a folder, data about that folder will be sent to your NestJS application.

What data about the folder (e.g. folder ID, auth of the folder, ...) will be sent from the React app to the NestJS app after the teacher selects the folder?
How can students submit assignments (files) and that file will be saved to the teacher's previously selected Google Drive folder?

Thanks for your response.
Example google picker:
google picker
Example upload file nodejs:
https://blog.tericcabrel.com/upload-file-to-google-drive-with-nodejs/

They cant drive picker is javascript which means theres no way for you to access another users drive account when they are offline.  Drive picker only lets you connect to your own account not others

@LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks for your comment,
link
Based on the upload a file section in the link above, my solution is to try to get the refresh token and folderID when the teacher selects the folder in Google Picker (the refresh token will be saved to the database).
When students submit their work, they will rely on the refresh token and folderId to upload to teacher's Google Drive.
Is it possible?

Client side JavaScript applications do not return a refresh token.  Only server side applications can get a refresh token.   Cant say i know a lot about picker but i thought it was client side. in which case you wont get a refresh token.
